# OWASP Zap Plug-In Development

Tags: owasp, zap

I need to develop a plugin for OWASP-Zap, but I can not build the project. There is a Quick Set Up for Eclipse but when I try to Team Project Set up then it fails and I have no idea why. Is there anybody here done something like that? I would appreciate if someone can help me.

```
The quickest way to set up a ZAP development environment is as follows:

1. Ensure you have a recent version of Eclipse - the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers is a good option (Ensure you have a version of Eclipse 4.2 or later installed or if using an earlier version, the "EGit - Git Team Provider" plug-in installed.)
2. Start Eclipse and select a new (empty) workspace
3. Select the menu: "File / Import"
4. Select "Team / Team Project Set" and click "Next >"
5. Select URL and enter: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zaproxy/zap-admin/master/ZAP-projectSet.psf
6. Click "Finish" and wait for Eclipse to pull down all of the projects and build them.
```

Comment: "but when I try to Team Project Set up then it fails" what fails? What's the message?

Comment: File not found was the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, the [psf was removed](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-admin/pull/146).

---

Check out these instructions > https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Contributing-Changes keep in mind that for the time being the master/beta/alpha branches in the extensions repo are all completely separate things (based on the status/quality of the extension(s)).

There's also a whole series of Blog posts that you might be interested in:

- https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2014/03/hacking-zap-1-why-should-you.html
- https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2014/03/hacking-zap-2-getting-started.html
- https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2014/04/hacking-zap-3-passive-scan-rules.html
- https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2014/04/hacking-zap-4-active-scan-rules.html

---

Edit 2022-05-03: There are updated Developer docs here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/developer/ including [Creating a New Add-on in zap-extensions](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/developer/creating-new-addon-in-zap-extensions/)

---

Edit 2022-05-24: There is now an example add-on repo available: https://github.com/zaproxy/addon-java